# Flutter pass Uint8List to iOS Objective-c

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, flutter

I am trying to pass an image as Uint8List  to native code Android/iOS from Flutter, but getting an error in iOS side. I am modifying a plugin and i never developed in iOS before.
Here is the Flutter code to capture an image from widget and send the Uint8List to native code.

```
  Future<void> _capturePng() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
    globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 1.50);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    printer.printImage(pngBytes);
  }
```

In Android, i am using Kotlin:

```
private fun printImage(call: MethodCall, result: Result) {
    val image = call.arguments as ByteArray
    val res = mPrinterPlugin.printImage(image)
    result.success(res)
}
```

In iOS, the plugin is written in Objective-C. i added this check for my image

```
else if([@"imagePrint" isEqualToString:call.method]){

     NSData *imgBytes = call.arguments;

     UIImage *label = [UIImage imageWithData:imgBytes];

 }
```

I saw that `Uint8List` is `FlutterStandardTypedData typedDataWithBytes` in iOS, but when i set the imgBytes type to it i get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take first argument as a typed data, probably:

```
NSArray *args = call.arguments;
FlutterStandardTypedData *list = args[0];
```

kotlin:

```
val args: List<Any> = call.arguments as List<Any>
val list = args[0] as ByteArray
```

and you invoke it like this:

```dart
Uint8List uint8List;
_channel.invokeMethod("your_function_name", [uint8List]);
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it and see

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this. Letting `Xcode` do its magical conversion was burning me.  For instance, in your iOS plugin implementation, the line:

```
NSData *imgBytes = call.arguments;
```

When i was doing this, in `Xcode` the debugger would see the data type would come through as a `FlutterStandardTypedData` (as i passed in a list of ints) but every time i would try to access an element/object it would give me memory errors.  It was like `Xcode` was honoring my parameter list (`NSArray`) in reality, but showing me the data type as a `FlutterStandardTypedData` while debugging.  Seemed like a bug in the `IDE` to be honest.

Just as the upvoted answer shows, i resolved by using the flutter data type:

```
FlutterStandardTypedData *bytesList = call.arguments[@"listOfBytes"];
```